# preg_match_all [200932]

Tags: php, numbers, preg-match-all

I want to preg_match [200932] this from a string.
I tryied some pattern but didnt help, any idea?

Comment: Show us the pattern you tried. Does it need to include the [] characters?

Comment: Hy thanks here is the pattern i tryied #[([.])]#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very vague but I think you probably forgot to escape the square brackets. They denote a character class in RegEx.

```
preg_match('/\[200932\]/', $str, $matches);
```

If you were to use `/[200932]/` it would mean "2 or 0 or 9 or 3".

Edit:

To capture numbers between square brackets:

```
/\[(\d+)\]/
```

That's

```
\[    A square bracket
(     Start capturing group
 \d+  A digit, 1 or more times
)     End capturing group
\]     A closing square bracket
```

Comment: yours also doesnt work it returns array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "]"
  }

Comment: Thanks it worked array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "[200932]"
  }

Comment: this worked forme thank you:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "[200932]"
  }

Answer (score 1):

not sure if I understand your question right, but here is it anyway:

```
[\[\]0-9]{8}
```

Comment: no it doesnt work. Is that difficult to understand i want the numbers between the square brackets

Answer (score 1):

You tried: #[([.])]#

Try this: \[([0-9]*)\]

(Without the * the string matches only one digit and you used . which matches on all chars even a,b,c,- or /)